Exact definition of linear resistance
We are studying electric circuits in class and are now coming across resistance. Our professor classified types of resistance into four groups based on two factors:

linear and non-linear
time-varying and time-invariant

She defined a linear function in physics as one with such features:

a homogenous function: $f(ax) = af(x)$
$f(x + t) = f(x) + f(t)$

By this definition, a function like $f(t)=2t$ is linear and one like $f(t)=2t+1$ is non-linear.
However, in this example:
$$R(t) = R_2 + R_1\cos\omega t$$
Which involves the cosine function, she claims that it is linear which doesn't make sense to me. If someone could explain when a resistance is exactly considered linear or non-linear I would appreciate that.
The example:


Linear function or linear resistance? While function $f(t)=2t+1$ is linear, having a current-voltage dependence like $V=2I +1$ would be unusual.

I'd guess by "linear resistance" your teacher means a linear relation between voltage and current, i.e. $V=R I$, where R may depend on time (or "external" quantities such as temperature), but not on voltage or current.

Also, beware of a potential confusion: Your definition of linear is the usal algebraic one. Functions like $f(x)=x+1$ are not linear accoridng to this definition, but are sometimes called affine-linear. However, in many fileds it is common to call functions of this type (i.i., those whose graph is a stright line) "linear" as well

@RogerV. That has me confused as well. gandalf61 is saying that if we insert a fixed t into the equation then R(t) =V(t).I(t) which is Ohm's Law, so when do we not achieve this relation? What is an example of a non-linear resistance? As an example is when V == i^3 is the resulting resistance non-linear?

I think there is a confusion here - in gandalf61 answer $t$ is time, whereas in your definition of linearity it is a generic variable.

The function
$R(t) = R_2 + R_1\cos\omega t$
is clearly not linear in time $t$. However, for a fixed value of $t$, you have the relationship
$V(t) = I(t)R(t)$
which is linear.

@EasternSkill LEDs and diodes are two examples of components that have non-linear current-voltage curves.

ok what would the equation for that look like? For the v, i, and R

@EasternSkill Google "diode I-V curve". Lots of examples online.

You have stated the two tests, $f(ax)=af(x)$ and $f(x+t)=f(x)+f(t)$, which if satisfied means that the function $f(x)$ is linear.
In the context of your question the test is,
Does the graph of $v$ against $i$ go through the origin?
Is it a straight line?
The graphs that your professor drew for the v-i charateristics at an instant of time show that, using the test I have stated above, the resistor is linear at each instant of time.
A device with the characteritic $f(i) = v=3\,i+1$ is not linear as the straight line does not go though the origin and, for example, $f(5i)\ne 5f(i)$.
However in electrical theory an incremental resistance, $\dfrac{dv}{di}$, is defined and for the characteristic $v=3\,i+1$ the incremental resistance would be constant at $3\,\Omega$.
If $v=5\,i^2 \Rightarrow \dfrac{dv}{di}= 10\,i$ the incremental resistance varies with current.

Your diagram and the associated formulae puzzle me it that the contribution of $R_2$ to the total resistance varies with time!
It would help me, and probably others, if the handwritten text was translated into English.
